# Each but newly built item

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

Is there a shorthand for doing the following:

```
  <% @ticket.notes.each do |n| %>
    <% if n != @ticket.notes.last %>
      <div class="note">
        <p class="author">Note by <b>n.user.name</b></p>
        <p class="time"><%= time_ago_in_words(n.created_at) %></p>
        <p class="copy"><%= n.content %></p>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

So that there is no need to check if the item is the last item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should [slice the array](http://apidock.com/ruby/Array/%5B%5D) beforehand:

```
<% @ticket.notes[0..-2].each do |n| %>
  <div class="note">
    <p class="author">Note by <b>n.user.name</b></p>
    <p class="time"><%= time_ago_in_words(n.created_at) %></p>
    <p class="copy"><%= n.content %></p>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: i see what this is doing now, pulling out from 0 to the previous one twice.

Comment: @Joseph: I don't know what you mean with "previous one". It simply extract the elements with indices `0` through `-2` (which is the second last element).

Comment: I mean, I didn't realise you could use backward indices

Comment: @Joseph: Yeah, that's quite handy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
  <% @ticket.notes[0..-2].each do |n| %>
      <!--your html here-->
  <% end %>
```